# Wordpress REST API create users not working

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-rest-api

I want to create and retrieve users in my WordPress site using an AngularJS client application. I am using WP REST API (Version 2) plugin and JWT Authentication for WP REST API plugin. I am using the following code:

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('jwtAuth', []);
  app.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
      return {
        'request': function(config) {

          var token = localStorage.getItem("token");

          if (token) {
            config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
          }
          return config;
        }
      };
    });
  });

  app.controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {

    var apiHost = 'http://mytechpen.com/wp-json'
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    $http.post(apiHost + '/jwt-auth/v1/token', {
        username: 'test1',
        password: 'test123'
      })

      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data.token)
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);

        $http({

            url: apiHost + '/wp/v2/users',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
              username: 'test4',
              password: 'test123',
              email: 'test4@gmail.com'
            },
            header: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + response.data.token
            }
          })
          .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data)
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.error('Error', error);
          });

      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error', error);
      });
  });
})();
```

I am getting the token in the first request. But there is an error occurring in the 2nd request. That is: [image]

I thought this is a CROS issue, so I added

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

To the .htaccess file. After that I am not able to get the token, I am getting an error saying Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values.

Here is my htaccess file without the Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Apart from that I have added the configurations mentioned in JWT plugin document to wp-config file as well.

Comment: Did you restart apache after performing the updates? That was the main reason I had the problems in the first place.

Comment: @AdrianOprea i have no access to my server to restart services how can i restart apache via cpanel or via cron job? how can i apply my changes in htaccess. when i hit ctrl+F5 many  more times

Answer (score 0):

it work for me

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```